# OpenSSL Seg Fault after upgrading to Sierra - ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

I've upgraded a working development machine to Sierra and it can no longer deploy using Capistrano.

Tracking it down, the issue is with a call to

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
```

This results in

```
/Users/programmer1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin16.0.0]
```

I have another Mac which also upgraded to Sierra but it is fine.

I've built ruby, using rvm, against Openssl v0.9.8zg.

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7-p374 --autolibs=0 --with-openssl=~/builds/openssl-0.9.8zg
```

If I build rvm's ruby against system installed Openssl I can use Capistrano, but Authlogic fails when a user logins into the Ruby on Rails application with a set fault at SSL.

If I build rvm's ruby against OpenSSL v0.9.8zg then Authlogic works correctly, but Capistrano seg faults when connecting to the remote server.

I've tried setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the locally built OpenSSL v0.9.8 before running Capistrano but it still core dumps.

Ruby on Rails 2.3.18 (legacy Application).
Ruby 1.8.7-p374
OS X Sierra

Am out of ideas now how to proceed with this.

Update:

```
otool -L /Users/programmer1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin16.0.0/openssl.bundle

/Users/programmer1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin16.0.0/openssl.bundle:
/Users/programmer1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/libruby.dylib (compatibility version 1.8.0, current version 1.8.7)
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

shows that ruby is always using libssl1.0.0 and never 0.9.7

How can I tell rvm to link against 0.9.7 of SSL please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a solution to my own problem more as a note to myself and for anyone else having this issue in the future.

It appears that openssl (0.9.8) was compiled for 32 bit not 64.

I configured OpenSSL:

```
./config darwin64-x86_64-cc shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64
```

(see https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#OS_X )

then reinstalled ruby1.8.7 via rvm

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7-p374 --autolibs=0 --with-openssl --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64
```

Checking the loaded version

```
otool -L /Users/programmer1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin16.0.0/openssl.bundle
```

Comment: where to run the ./config darwin64-x86_64-cc shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64 command exactly?